# ES analysis date field

Tags: elasticsearch

I am loading data through log stash into ES. I have the following mapping.

```
"date_field": {"type" : "date", "index":"true", "store":"true", 
               "format":"dd-MM-yyyy'T'HH:mm:ssZ", "ignore_malformed":true}
```

My date field is `21-05-2001T23:59:59Z`. When I try to load this field, I am getting an exception.

1. How do I analysis that this field works? I tried `_analyze` and it throws an error `that the field is not tokenised`. I think that I need to specify tokenizer. Does standard analyser not sufficient?
2. Any clue on this?

Parse exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
failed to parse date field [13-07-2011T23:59:59Z] with format 
    [dd-MM-yyyy'T'HH:mm:ssZ]
```

But when I remove `Z` from my input date, it works. I am not sure how to parse `Z`.

Comment: What is the error you are getting

Comment: Parse exception it says when I remove `ignore_malformed`

Comment: And since it is a date field, it is not tokenised by default I guess. So I get `Analysis requests are only supported on tokenized field` when trying to analyze

Comment: Can you please update your question with the exact error you get (i.e. the ParseException)?

Comment: @Val Please see my edit

Comment: Which ES version are you using?

Comment: 7.6.2 version Val.